# Android SDK Version 25 - android.support v7:25 gives "No resource found that matches @color/hint_foreground_material_light" Adobe Creative SDK?

Tags: android, android-support-library, adobecreativesdk, android-7.1-nougat

I get the following error while the gradle sync/build after switching the compileSdkVersion to 25 and using the latest android.support library versions.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
```

Error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColorHint' with value '@color/hint_foreground_material_light').
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**
I think thats because of Adobe Creative SDK... Not sure. Others are running fine with SDK 25.

Related question: [error while using the support library with adobe creative SDK for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378779/error-while-using-the-support-library-with-adobe-creative-sdk-for-android)

We should not wait for a solution... Maybe there is a newer version as I am using ('com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.6.3')

**EDIT2:** I found out that this is coming from "fengdai alertdialog" which is a Adobe SDK dependency. But DEPRECATED! I asked Adobe for some support.

Comment: Have you heard back from Adobe yet?

Comment: "Thanks for reaching out and informed us about the issue. I forwarded the info to the appropriate team and will have it add to the bug fix queue.

In the meantime, you should able to use the SDK with the support library 24.1.1."

Comment: First, thank you for your effort. But even with 24.1.1 the error is still there, how about you?

Comment: I don't remember what version I use. I have to check this. I re-asked adobe if there are any news.

Comment: I found a solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution:
Add these lines to your colors.xml:

```
<color name="hint_foreground_material_light">#00000000</color>
<color name="hint_foreground_material_dark">#00000000</color>
```

That is a workaround until adobe fixes the problem.

Works with v10.0.0 and should also work with all others.

Answer from ADOBE:

> The plan is to officially release it this week. With that said, we do
>   have the updated version available for download already, but the doc
>   of the integration on the website is not updated. If you like you can
>   use the doc we have on github.

Comment: A new [Creative Cloud SDK](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2017/02/announcing-creative-sdk-v0-9-1251-for-android/) has already supported Android SDK level 25

Answer (score 2):

Same with me, now i'm just downgrading it into 24.2.1 version and the error is gone. I'm pretty sure that this is one of support library bugs.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. Let me know if you have any news.

Comment: Hi, I reverted back to 24.2.1 , but the error is still there. I have clean build, restart and invalidate cache , but no benefit. Any Idea?

Comment: @Sac How did you resolve this? I'm also using the Adobe Creative SDK.

Comment: @jah15 My issue was not using a correct facebook sdk version. Initially i was giving a range,but giving a fixed version like (**compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'**) solved the issue. If you are not using fb sdk, some other dependency might be causing the issue.

Comment: If apps have already been released with     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+' will that cause issues?  Should we be republishing apps with specific versions?