# Error when trying to implement CreativeSDK

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I am trying to put dependencies in build.gradle as per the CreativeSDK guidelines.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "andMKD.IMGEDIT"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1062'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
}
```

But I am receiving the following error as soon as I sync this

> Information:Total time: 11.751 secs
>   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>   Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for debug
>   Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.2.1 for release
>   /home/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml
>   Error:(2352, 44) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColorHint' with value '@color/hint_foreground_material_light').
>   Error:(2352, 44) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColorHint' with value '@color/hint_foreground_material_light').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:3 errors
>   Information:2 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: please check `hint_foreground_material_light` is avialable in `color.xml`

Comment: I tried to put it manually but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creative SDK docs says:

> The Creative SDK supports Android API Level 16 as the lowest
>   minSdkVersion, and API Level 24 as the maximum targetSdkVersion

so try to downgrade it to 24 if possible, or try the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248008/android-sdk-version-25-android-support-v725-gives-no-resource-found-that-mat)